# toggling the popup content wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup, toggle

Here is what I am trying to do.

### Toggle button 1 (editNameOpen)

- When checked, show the popup content
- The only way to close it is from another toggle button inside of the popup (editNameClose)

### Toggle button 2 (editNameClose)

- this inside of the popup
- when IsChecked, close the popup AND make editNameOpen closed

Here is some xaml I'm using to try and work out the kinks. Problems / questions so far:

1. My MultiBinding is wrong and throws a runtime error "Cannot set MultiBinding because MultiValueConverter must be specified." What would the MultiValueConverter  be converting in this case?
2. How would I close the 1st toggle button when the 2nd is checked?

Cheers,
Berryl

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="editNameOpen" Style="{StaticResource EditToggleButtonStyle}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>

<Popup x:Name="popupNameEditingControl"
       PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=editeditNameOpenName}"
       PopupAnimation="Slide"
       StaysOpen="False"    ** shoulf this be true?
       MinWidth="50">

    ** open and stay open while until editNameClose is checked
    <Popup.IsOpen>
        <MultiBinding >
            <Binding Mode="OneWay" ElementName="editNameOpen" Path="IsChecked"/>
            <Binding Mode="OneWay" ElementName="editNameClose" Path="IsChecked" Converter="{StaticResource invertBoolConv}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Popup.IsOpen>

    ** how do we reset editNameOpen to be NOT IsChecked when editNameClose is checked?
    ** how do we reset editNameClose to be NOT IsChecked and then reset editNameClose to also be not checked when this opens again?
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}">
        <Label Content="Hello Wolrd!"/>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="editNameClose" Content="X"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Popup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would bind `Popup.IsOpen` and both `ToggleButtons` to a single boolean property in the `DataContext`

So when the first `ToggleButton` gets checked, it sets the boolean value to `true`, which makes `Popup.IsOpen` evaluate as `true` and open the `Popup`

The second `ToggleButton` will probably need to use a `Converter` to reverse the boolean property, so it shows as unchecked when `IsOpen = true`, and checking it will make `IsOpen = false`, which will automatically close the `Popup` and uncheck the first `ToggleButton`

As for the error you're getting, a `MultiBinding` expects a `Converter` of type `IMultiValueConverter` because you cannot bind one property to two separate values. You need a converter to convert those values into a single value you can use.

If you really want to do it this way instead of using a property in the `DataContext`, try binding the `IsOpen` property of the `Popup` and the `IsChecked` properties of your `ToggleButtons` all together.

```
<Popup x:Name="popupNameEditingControl"
       IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=editNameOpen, Mode=TwoWay}"
       ... >
    ...
    <ToggleButton x:Name="editNameClose" Content="X"
                  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=editNameOpen, 
                      Converter={StaticResource ReverseBooleanConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    ...
</Popup>
```

Comment: I originally was using the vm to control this and then decided this really was a view only affair. It *does* sound simpler though, but I'll work through the view only approach first at least as an exercise. Cheers

Comment: IF you have a concept for how that Popup.Style should look would love to see it!

Comment: @Berryl Personally I hate WPF's built-in Popup control and usually use my own custom `UserControl` instead. You can find the code [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/popup-panel-for-wpf/) if you're interested

Comment: @Berryl I also added a code sample for binding the `IsOpen` and `IsChecked` properties together to my answer